# Firebase UI Provider Error More specific Error Messages Possible?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase UI to let my users loggin but the default error message is not a good one I handled all the signin options well. So the only way the error message pops ups when the user cancelled a selected sign in method or they have no internet or firebase have problems. Can I make a more specific error message then Provider error in Firebase UI for android java

Comment: Or atleast disable the proivder error message when the user just cancelled a signin method because there is not really a problem when the user does so it doesn't make sense to show a error message

Comment: If you have suggestion on improving an error message, simply open an issue and suggest it in the [FirebaseUI-android repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues).